# WPF User Control Binding Issue?

Tags: wpf, binding, itemssource

I have this:

```
public MyView: UserControl
{
  public IList<Person> PersonList { get; set; } 

  public MyView()
  {
   //code
  }

  public void Display(MyData myData)
  {
    DataContext=myData;
  }
  //code
}
```

The XAML for this includes a ComboBox :

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PersonList}"
```

For some reason this does not work and the combo box does not get populated ( however, If I use the code-behind and I say comboBox.ItemsSource = PersonList  then the combo box does got populated ).

Any ideas ?

Regards,
MadSeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your property is set to private, and are you sure that you are setting the DataContext.

*** EDIT ***

Based on the change you made above, you're setting your datacontext incorrectly.  Your "PersonList" is an`IList<>` on your MyView class, but you're setting your data context to something else.

Try adding items to PersonList within MyView and setting `this.DataContext = this;`  Also, as suggested, switch your `IList<>` to an `ObservableCollection<>`.

I would also highly suggest reading up on the Model View ViewModel (MVVM) approach.  It will help out a lot.  Josh Smith has a lot of good articles about the MVVM approach (and has written a good book about it too).

Here's a link to his [blog](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/).  His book is linked there, as well.

Comment: I tried making the property public and no result. And I'm sure that I'm setting the DataContext. I just made a change to my initial post to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you're not firing any property-changed events.  If you don't notify your UI when the property's value is first set, the binding won't update.  Look into the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and implement it in your class.

Similarly, if your `IList` property isn't an `ObservableCollection` or doesn't implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, then when you add items to the list the databound UI won't reflect this.

Comment: oddly enough I do build the IList as an ObservableCollection

Answer (score 0):

I believe your binding statement is the problem.
"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PersonList}" is looking for a "PersonList" on the combobox itself.

Are you seeing any binding errors in the output window?

Ideally you'd want to bind to a property in your DataContext (MyData)